# Goldbach Cryptarithm

Tags: mathematics, alphametic

As the apology for the mischievous problem about knights and knaves:

```
  PRIME
  PRIME
+ PRIME
-------
 NUMBER
```

Yeah, this was inspired by the famous (or infamous) Goldbach Conjecture.

Comment: Do all 8 letters have to be distinct digits?

Comment: @smci Yes. That's a common rule for alphametic puzzles.

Comment: @PSPark sometimes it is, sometimes not (obviously not when there are >9 letters involved), but the tag doesn't specify, nor does this question, and you have a second answer with non-distinct digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If PRIME is a prime number, then the solution is:

> **there is no solution**

If PRIME is not a prime number, the solution is:

> **PRIME = 54328**, NUMBER = 162984

Also:

> Found an [alphametic solver](http://www.tkcs-collins.com/truman/alphamet/alpha_solve.shtml) for faster solutions.

Comment: It is usual in these problems that a different letter represents a different digit.  Also, a number doesn't start with a zero.  On the other side, it wasn't specified that PRIME is a prime.  So your last solution can be considered as the only proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is:

> **PRIME = 81957**, NUMBER = 245871

Comment: Your P and B are the same.